# using switch in get request in express js is returning error why?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

so I'm still a beginner in nodejs , and when I run http://127.0.0.1:3000/ in the browser I get this message, `Cannot GET /` I think, it is because I used a switch statement. can't I use a switch inside `app.get` ? I want to make the code DRY that's why I used a switch.

```
 const express = require('express');
        const app = express();
        const port = 3000;
        const hostname = 'localHost';
        app.get('/:main/:sub/:sub2', (req, res) => {
            let main = String(req.params.main).toLowerCase();
            let sub = String(req.params.sub).toLowerCase();
            let sub2 = String(req.params.sub2).toLowerCase();
            switch (main) {
                case "":
                    res.send(`Hi there welcome to my assignment`);
                case "speak":
                    {
                        switch (sub) {
                            case "pig":
                                res.send(`The pig says 'Oink'`);
                            case "cow":
                                res.send(`The cow says 'Moo'`);
                            case "dog":
                                res.send(`The dog says 'Woof Woof!'`);
                            case "*":
                                res.send(`sorry no one speaks here!`);
                        }
                    }
                case "repeat":
                    {
                        if (sub2 === !NaN) {
                            for (let i = 0; i < sub2; i++) {
                                res.send(`${sub}`);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                default:
                    res.send(`Page not found!`);
            }
        });
        app.listen(port, hostname, () => {
            console.log(`server has started`)
        });
```

Comment: you didn't define a default route. `app.get("/", (req, res) => { res.send("home page")});`

Comment: I did in the switch I made case "":

Comment: I even made app.get("/", (req, res) => { res.send("home page")}); but I still get Cannot GET /sub but I do get home page when I run the server but I still can't get any subpage

Comment: That's invalid. You have to remove your original case.

Comment: You should have `break;` at the end of each `case`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your empty string case isn't a valid parameter to search for within `main`.

Create a default route using `app.get` instead:

```
 const express = require('express');
        const app = express();
        const port = 3000;
        const hostname = 'localHost';
        app.get("/", (req, res) => res.send("Welcome to my assignment"));
        app.get('/:main/:sub/:sub2', (req, res) => {
            let main = String(req.params.main).toLowerCase();
            let sub = String(req.params.sub).toLowerCase();
            let sub2 = String(req.params.sub2).toLowerCase();
            switch (main) {
                case "speak":
                    {
                        switch (sub) {
                            case "pig":
                                res.send(`The pig says 'Oink'`);
                                break;
                            case "cow":
                                res.send(`The cow says 'Moo'`);
                            break;
                            case "dog":
                                res.send(`The dog says 'Woof Woof!'`);
                            break;
                            case "*":
                                res.send(`sorry no one speaks here!`);
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                case "repeat":
                    {
                        if (!Number.isNaN(sub2)) {
                            let str = "";
                            for (let i = 0; i < sub2; i++) {
                                str+=sub;

                            }
                            res.send(str);
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                default:
                    res.send(`Page not found!`);
                    break;
            break;
            }
        });
        app.listen(port, hostname, () => {
            console.log(`server has started`)
        });
```

**Edit** I also adjusted the "repeat" functionality to work. `!NaN` is always `true`. Your original code basically said `if(sub2 === true)` which it never would be. I modified it using the `!Number.isNaN` conditional method. I then concatenated a string and output it `n` number of times.

Comment: I still  receive "Cannot GET /repeat/hello" for example, but ,I do get home page when I run the server but I still can't get any subpage

Comment: @AbdullahZareaa I updated to show why that was. Any further questions on this should be in a new question.

Comment: thanks for your modification but the code isn't working I want to know the issue, I still receive  "Cannot GET /subpage"

Comment: You need `break` at the end of each `case`.

Comment: @AbdullahZareaa What route are you not hitting?

Comment: guys can some one run the code to see that it still holds the issue  "Cannot GET /subpage" I added the break statement and the issue holds!

Comment: ... @AbdullahZareaa you wrote the routes. I _don't_ know what routes you're not able to hit unless you tell me. I'm able to hit them.

Comment: @AbdullahZareaa are you talking about "/speak/pig" ? because of course you're not able to hit that.  try "/speaking/pig/1" The route you specified requires three parameters. You need to put in all of the query parameters, regardless of if they're used. That's the way the logic you wrote works.

Comment: I wrote http://127.0.0.1:3000/ it worked , then I wrote http://127.0.0.1:3000/repeat/hello/5 it worked , but http://127.0.0.1:3000/speak/cow doesn't

Comment: @AbdullahZareaa see my above comment.

Comment: @zfrisch exactly but can't I make that 3rd param empty as default

Comment: @AbdullahZareaa I understand you're frustrated but you need to ask a new question. Questions aren't meant to be "resolve everything that isn't working for me" - they're specific. I already answered your initial route question.